# Why am I not able to check/uncheck checkboxes?

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to check/uncheck checkboxes, but their checkmark value is being populated by the api and either checking them or leaving them unchecked. But for some reason I am not able to check/uncheck.

Tried putting them into different components and using onClick/onChange. Nothing works.

Parent component - PublishPage:

```js
<div id="all-roles">
   {this.props.listOfRoles ? (
  <ListOfRoles checkedIDs={this.state.roleIDs} roles={this.props.listOfRoles} /> ) : null}
</div>
```

List of Roles

```js
export default class ListOfRoles extends Component {
 state = {
   checkedIDs : []
 }

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
  let checkedIDs = null;
  if (props.checkedIDs) {
    checkedIDs = props.checkedIDs
  }

  return { checkedIDs: checkedIDs };
}

  render() {    
        const roles = this.props.roles[0].roles;

        console.log(this.state);
        return (
          <div id="assign-to-role">
            {roles.map(role => {
              return (
                <div>
                    <RoleCheckbox roleName={role.roleName} roleID={role.roleID} checkedArray={this.state.checkedIDs} />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      } 
  }
```

RoleCheckbox

```js
export default class RoleCheckbox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checkboxDefault: true
        }

        this.handleCheckbox = this.handleCheckbox.bind(this);
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
        let checked = true;
        let roleID = props.roleID;
        let checkedArray = props.checkedArray;

        if (checkedArray.indexOf(roleID) !== -1) {
          checked = true
        } else {
          checked = false;
        }

        return { checkboxDefault: checked };
      }


    handleCheckbox(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: !this.state[e.target.name]
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label> {this.props.roleName}
                    <input 
                        type="checkbox" 
                        name="checkboxDefault" 
                        onChange={this.handleCheckbox} 
                        checked={this.state.checkboxDefault} />
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to be able to check/uncheck and also I want to be able to load them as checked if the api says they should be checked.

Comment: Your component has one checkbox. You know the name for the state variable. Use that name, don't use `[e.target.name]`. Also don't call it "default". A default is a value that's used in absence of a real value. By all means, use a `const checkboxDefault = false` and then in your constructor set `this.state = { checked: checkboxDefault }` but don't directly use defaults in `render()`. Use `this.state.checked` and update _that_ value in your change handler. Now, with all that said: create a [mcve]: you only need an `<App>` that creates a single `<RoleCheckbox>`, and only the code for checking.

Answer (score -1):

Actually what's happening here is that you are injecting the HTML with the boolean value from `this.state.checkboxDefault` which is initialized default to true inside `RoleCheckbox` component and the function that handles the change is not effecting the state. Change the state and it will reflect on the UI as well

```
handleCheckbox(e) {
    this.setState({
       checkboxDefault: !this.state.checkboxDefault
    })
}
```

Comment: This is what the OP has already, only you hardcoded the value in a different place then they did. It shouldn't have any affect.